# What is the closed subscheme of $A^2_R$ defined by $x^2+y^2 = -1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read the [Scheme (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)#Motivation_for_schemes).
The page says the following:
"The closed subscheme of $A^2_R$ defined by $x^2+y^2 = -1$ is a nonempty topological space."
But I don't understand the meaning of "The closed subscheme of $A^2_R$ defined by $x^2+y^2 = -1$" because of my lack of ability.
The definition of closed subscheme I know is:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Closed_subscheme 
However I don't know more than the definition.
I'd appreciate if you could answer thisquestions.

Comment: It is $V(x^2 + y^2 + 1) \subseteq \text{Spec} \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. That is, the collection of prime ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ containing $(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ in the Zariski topology

Comment: An answer to this might not be satisfactory as it will present you with even more jargon to learn.  This is just talking about a curve in the xy-plane, but about to be generalized to a very large class of numbers. It seems what you really want is to google for a text on "introduction to algebraic geometry" -- there are many choices.

Comment: They mean  it is $\; \operatorname{Spec}\mathbf R[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2+1)$, as in their 2nd example.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I will study more.